# ATOM XML is not accepted by IBM Connections Server

Tags: atom-feed, ibm-connections, ibm-sbt

I want to post this XML (generated by C# SyndicationItem ) to an IBM Connections 4.0 OAuth EndPoint:

https:/HOSTNAME/forums/oauth/atom/replies?topicUuid=ee5878b5-65d4-4d44-8192-367e49c30e91

The servers return error 400, bad request. What could be wrong in this XML ?

The Bearer and ContentType headers are set.

```
<entry xmlns:thr="http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0"     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
  <id>uuid:3201e3e0-2d17-4f8c-9f69-22bd7cbb1443;id=1</id>
<title
type="text">re: test voor topic</title>
<updated>2013-08-14T15:27:43Z</updated>
<content
type="text">fetre</content>
<category
scheme="http://www.ibm.com/xmlns/prod/sn/type"
term="forum-reply" xmlns=""></category>
<in-reply-to
ref="urn:lsid:ibm.com:forum:ee5878b5-65d4-4d44-8192-367e49c30e91"
href="https://HOSTNAME/forums/atom/topic?topicUuid=ee5878b5-65d4-4d44-8192-367e49c30e91" 
xmlns="http://purl.org/syndication/thread/1.0"></in-reply-to>
</entry>
```

Comment: I'm just beginning to look at your post, and it occurs to me what method are you using from the endpoint?  post, put?

Comment: post. Since this is the best I can do with C#'s SyndicationItem, I continued an a different path (String with replacements). This works but SyndicationItem seemed the right way go. So I am stil wandering what is wrong with this XML.

Comment: it's probably the :id=1

Answer (score 0):

There are two things you want to double check 
1) I wonder if you need an id element in the atom entry, in the example of Connections forums API document, no id is provided
2) I notice you use the topic uuid in

> ref="urn:lsid:ibm.com:forum:ee5878b5-65d4-4d44-8192-367e49c30e91"

, in fact, you should use the correct forum uuid instead of the topic id.

Comment: the data is ok, I tried it by posting a manually constructed XML message. I think I'll continue on this road. To bad though, the C# SyndicationItem class seemed a good fit.